# Difference between crawling and indexing

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, google-cache

If a website is cached, does it mean that it has been indexed too?

[image]

In this snapshot cache date is shown as 18th may but when i did site search for this domain I found 0 pages were indexed by google last week.

Comment: wow, you surely know how to print screen.

Comment: Please see my answer on your other question. Indexed and cached are the same. These are not two separate things.

Comment: This is not about cache being broken. This question is about the page being cached but not being indexed.
 Date stamp shown in cached copy is 18th may( yesterday). When i try to find out number of pages google indexed last week i couldn't find even a single page.

Hope it clarifies the previous question

Comment: I'm confused... you state that the page was not indexed _last week_, but the cache is only from _yesterday_. Are you saying that the page is still not indexed? If the page is not indexed, how are you seeing the cached page?

Comment: @w3dk yes, This is exactly what I wanted to say. website is being cached but not being indexed.
I checked the cache at this URL http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://paintcollar.com

Comment: But the page _is indexed_: `site:paintcollar.com`.

Comment: Yes,this page was indexed by Google 1 year ago but content in this page keeps changing so Links in this page also keep changing. This page was cached on 18th  may so all the direct URLs in this Page should also have been indexed but that didn't happen.

Comment: "so all the direct URLs in this Page should also have been indexed" - not necessarily. Just because one page is indexed doesn't mean that Google has crawled and indexed all the connecting pages - if that is was you are implying?

Comment: When a page is fetched, the links found within the page are immediately entered into the index (assuming they are not already in the index) and the link target pages are queued to be fetched. This is a huge list of URLs! Some will have to be prioritized higher than others so getting through the queue can take a while sometimes. Nothing is immediate in search. It is simply impossible. However, Google *does* want to index as many pages as possible as quickly as possible, but not at the expense of pages that are popular, fresh, and trending.

Answer (score 1):

When Google fetches a page, it is immediately stored within the index. This is where the cache comes from. The page is indexed.

When you do a site: search, this is NOT a reliable indication of whether the page is indexed or not. The reason for this is simple. The process is not simple. There is a fair amount of work that has to be done before a page will show up in the SERPs. Generally, this is not a slow process, however, it is also not immediate.

While the site: search directive is unique and often more complete, any SERP (search engine result page) list is a byproduct of quite a few algorithms regardless. All of the algorithms require metrics that may not have been collected yet. Some of these algorithms are filters that will prevent a page from being displayed. It is very possible that a page that has been fetched and cached will not show up in the SERPs even with a site: search directive. At least, not for a few days. Under normal conditions, this all works fairly quickly and works as expected.

*I am making an assumption.*

If you are using Google's Search Console to Fetch and Render / Submit to Index, please know this is an incomplete process. Because this feature has been abused, it has been modified. When you do a Fetch as Google / Submit to Index, it is temporary and incomplete. The regular googlebot will visit within 1-2 days and will make it all official.

*You have to remember this.*

Search engines are not real-time and do not work on your schedule. Period. You cannot hurry them up and you really should not try. With search engines, the best tool in the box is patience. We all go through the same thing. Your site is important to you and so is everyone elses. You are not the only worrying about how Google sees your site.

You are fine. Do not worry so much. Please. You are too young for that!

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc for reply. Google is showing that it has indexed only 9-10 URLs in last month(which is sufficient time, I guess) and this is what is worrying me. There is no point of site optimization if google is not crawling and indexing properly. :(

Comment: @Aboy It will. Google is particularly slow as any search engine is. Generally, it will take anywhere from 30-60 days before Google indexes a site. Do not be surprised if it never seems to complete the process. Use the Fetch as Google to make sure that Google can fetch your pages okay. But only test one or two. After that, just leave it alone. Any new site owner goes through the same thing you are going through. ;-) We all get itchy! We think, Dang it! Where the hell are you?? We worry that we are doing something wrong. Just make sure your site is as good as it can be and create good content.

Comment: @Aboy I just checked your robots.txt file. If you are not trying to block anything, I suggest having a blank file. Your current robots.txt directive looks incomplete to me. You can always test your robots.txt file using Googles Search Console. The option is in there somewhere, I just forget what the specific option is. This could be something to check. Again, if you are not intending to block anything, a blank file is recommended. As well, it is always recommended that a robots.txt file exist even if it is blank. Cheers!!

Comment: I have checked the  robots.txt file but it didn't return any error. Is this OK to leave robots.txt blank? I need to work on making website crawler friendly though and upload the updated sitemap as well. 
Thanks a lot, you were very helpful!!